# Replacing a character (translating python code to JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to translate a simple python code to JavaScript. The python code is pretty much replacing a character with another character and prints out the results. My python code is

```
def replace(word):
        for old, new in (
            ("a", "@"),
            ("e", "()"),
            ):
            s = word.replace(old, new)            
        print (s)
```

For JavaScript I cant get my head around translating it. I tried to do something like iterating but it seems to be a sloppy code

```
function replace(character) {
    for(var i = 0; i<word.length;i++) {
        ...}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript already has a native method to replace chars in a string:

```
 var txt = 'old text';
 console.log(txt.replace('old', 'new'));
```

Note that this method will only replace the first match of your text, anyway you can make a 'replace all' using regex. Check out the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace).

**[Update]**

```
function replace(str){
  return str.replace(/a/g, '@').replace(/\(\)/g, 'e').replace(/h/g, '+');  
}
```

The **'g'** char at the end of the regex is used to say that the method should replace all occurrences.

Comment: What if I have more than one character that needs to be replaced?

Comment: @Robben The replace method accepts a string or a regex, so you can replace whatever you want. You can also chain the replaces: txt.replace('a', 'A').replace('b', 'B').replace('c', 'C');

Comment: So the syntax of replacing whichever character I want in a string will be `txt.replace('a', 'A').replace('b', 'B').replace('c', 'C')`?

Comment: @Robben please give an example of your original text and the expected result, so I can say you the best way to do it.

Comment: Well, I want to create a function `replace` where the parameter is a string. Within that string I want to change some of the characters, like changing 'a' to '@', 'e' to '()', 'h' to '+'. And the function will print out the new string. So lets say I call `replace('hate')` then the function `replace` should print out `+@t()`.

Comment: @Robben check out the answer again.